# How to call components inside a components with pods structure in ember cli

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have 2 components x-foo and y-foo in a pods structure.

> app/pods/components/x-foo/template.hbs
>   app/pods/components/y-foo/template.hbs

I want to call y-foo component inside x-foo component's template.hbs like this:

```
<section>
  {{y-foo}}
</section>
```

But it errors out saying that y-foo helper doesn't exist. Can anyone show me the right way to do this in a pods structure?

Comment: did you have app/pods/components/x-foo/component.js, app/pods/components/y-foo/component.js file as well?

Comment: Yes I did have those as well

Comment: humm did you set up the podModulePrefix in environment.js file. Also i would be curious to try "ember generate component x-foo" and same for y-foo and see if that version works.

Comment: Yes.

`modulePrefix: 'my-app',podModulePrefix: 'my-app/pods'`. It seems that for the non-pod version, the helper not found error is gone but y-foo isn't being rendered. I'm probably doing something wrong, or nested components are not allow.ed

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to fix this by creating the parent component with a path and calling the child component via {{component y-foo}}.

> ember generate component x-foo --pod --path x

Will generate x-foo component in

> app/pods/x/x-foo/component.js
>
> app/pods/x/x-foo/template.hbs

In x-foo component template, call y-foo component like this:

```
<section>
  {{component y-foo}}
</section>
```

The reason for this question is because I'm trying to future-proof my Ember 1.x for Ember 2.0. I'm not sure though if I'm doing the right thing, but this looks okay in my opinion.

Comment: Ah, my bad. While the _Assertion Failed: A helper named 'y-foo' could not be found_ is gone, nothing is being rendered for y-foo.

Comment: `podModulePrefix: config.podModulePrefix` was missing in app.js which caused the problems. Please ignore my answer above.

Comment: I know the answer to this but it will have to wait until I'm at a computer. I think I had to place the component like this {{component 'my/nested/y-foo'}} ie., include the path to the component

Comment: I've fixed my problem by adding the podModulePrefix: config.podModulePrefix in my app.js. Thanks though.

Comment: Can you add that as an answer?

Comment: @ChristopherMilne, it was simply a bug in Ember CLI because they removed podModulePrefix in app.js

They have however, returned it in Ember CLI 0.2.6 so using that version and above will no longer give the error that I'm having here.

Sorry for the late reply :(

Answer (score 0):

Add  `podModulePrefix: config.podModulePrefix` in your app.js